# MIME type changes if file edited in *nix systems

Tags: linux, libreoffice, mime-types

I have an excel file created in Windows machine.

If I check MIME type with `file -b --mime users.xlsx` the result is `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=binary`

So far it's OK. But when I edit the same file in Ubuntu with LibreOffice and save it, the result of the `file` command becomes `application/zip; charset=binary`

So whose fault is this? LibreOffice? And what can I do to prevent it? I'm using this file in my website's upload form. When validating MIME types it causes errors.

**EDIT: More Info**

I use PHP and Symfony in the website. Symfony first uses fileinfo extension of PHP to determine the MIME type. If it fails it runs `file -b --mime-type` command. And `fileinfo` extension returns `application/octet-stream` which is also incorrect.

**Note:***This also happens in Mac*

Comment: what is the output of `mimetype users.xlsx` ?

Comment: @Rahul, `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

Comment: Looks like LibreOffice wrote out some sort of compressed xls file instead of a standard one. What does `unzip -v <file>` show? And what's the file's name?

Comment: I didn't fix the issue. But i  think i know the problem. LibreOffice puts different `magic` bytes to the file. So `file` command can't recognize it. Its a know issue in the internet. But there is no fix i think.